# How to pick media files in Xamarin forms for both iOS and Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to find some way which can be used to pick photos within forms without writing platform specific code in both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `xam.Plugin.Media` from NuGet.

```
//...
using Plugin.Media;
//...

async void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

   if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
      await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
      return;
    }

   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

   if (file == null)
     {
       return;
     }

   else
     {
       await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
     }

}
```

Don't forget add `Privacy`

> in iOS (info.plist)

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
```

> in Android

if your users are running Marshmallow the Plugin will automatically prompt them for runtime permissions. You must add the Permission Plugin code into your Main or Base Activities:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

For more detail you can access [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)